# MVC-5 WebGrid adding Column headers as actionlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am dynamically adding columns to a Web-grid using MVC-5 and C# and when the grid renders everything looks fine but the column headers won't function as an action Links. There are two versions of the code and both render but don't function as Action Links. 
Thank you for your help.

```
    cols.Add(grid.Column(Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(), Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                   format: @<Text>@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.DictionaryList[i].Values.ElementAt(i).ToString(), "Select_MSPart_Search",
                   "MaterialSupply", new
                   {
                       id = ViewData["id"],
                       type = 1,
                       SearchFilter = Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                       SearchValue = "",
                       rowsPerPage = 7
                   })</Text>, style: "column-action"));

     cols.Add(grid.Column(header: Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),columnName:  Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                                format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink((string)Model.DictionaryList[i].Values.ElementAt(i).ToString(), "Select_MSPart_Search",
                                "MaterialSupply", new
                                {
                                    id = ViewData["id"],
                                    type = 1,
                                    SearchFilter = Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                                    SearchValue = "",
                                    rowsPerPage = 7
                                },null).ToHtmlString()), style: "column-action"));
```

Everything seems to render correctly except the column headers are not Action Links as I had hoped for. I also tried the second piece of code with the same results.
Thank you for your help.
I realized that seeing the entire view would be critical because I am building the grid dynamically.

```
    @using System.Dynamic
@using System.Linq
@using System.Data.Common
@using CeleroPortal.Models.ConstraintsAnalysis
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using System.Web.Mvc.Razor
@model mdlViews
@using PagedList.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View Report records Page";
    var result = new List<dynamic>();
    int rowcnt = 0;
    foreach (var recRow in Model.DlList)
    {
        var row = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();
        Dictionary<string, object> eachFieldRow = (Dictionary<string, object>)recRow;     //for when list was string,object
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in eachFieldRow)
        {
            row.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        }
        result.Add(row);
        rowcnt++;
    }

    //WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: result, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, canSort: true, sortFieldName: Model.Sort, sortDirectionFieldName: Model.SortDir);
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize, canPage: true, canSort: false, sortFieldName: Model.Sort, sortDirectionFieldName: Model.SortDir);
    List<WebGridColumn> cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Order ID","Order ID"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Part ID", "Part ID"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Description", "Description"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Customer ID", "Customer ID"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Customer", "Customer"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Qty Due", "Quantity Due"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Target Date", "Target Date"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Days", "Days"));
    cols.Add(grid.Column("Final Date", "Final Date"));
    for (int i = 9; i < Model.DictionaryList[0].Count(); i++)
    {
        if (Model.DictionaryList[0].Keys.ElementAt(i).StartsWith("#"))
        {
            cols.Add(grid.Column(Model.DictionaryList[0].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(), Model.DictionaryList[0].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            //cols.Add(grid.Column(Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),header: Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
            //   format: (Model) => Html.ActionLink((string)Model.DictionaryList[i].Values.ElementAt(i).ToString(), "Select_MSPart_Search",
            //   "MasterSupply",new { id = ViewData["id"] , type = 1, SearchFilter = Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString() , SearchValue = "",
            //   rowsPerPage = 7}),style: "column-action"));
            cols.Add(grid.Column(header:Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),columnName: Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                       format: @<Text>@Html.ActionLink((string)Model.DictionaryList[i].Values.ElementAt(i).ToString(), "Select_MSPart_Search",
                       "MaterialSupply", new
                       {
                           id = ViewData["id"],
                           type = 1,
                           SearchFilter = Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
                           SearchValue = "",
                           rowsPerPage = 7
                       })</Text>, style: "column-action"));
            //cols.Add(grid.Column(header: Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),columnName: Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
            //                        format: (item) => @Html.ActionLink((string)Model.DictionaryList[i].Values.ElementAt(i).ToString(), "Select_MSPart_Search",
            //                        "MaterialSupply", new
            //                        {
            //                            id = ViewData["id"],
            //                            type = 1,
            //                            SearchFilter = Model.DictionaryList[i].Keys.ElementAt(i).ToString(),
            //                            SearchValue = "",
            //                            rowsPerPage = 7
            //                        }, null)));
        }
    }
    grid.Bind(result, rowCount: Model.TotalRecords, autoSortAndPage: true);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All);
}

<style type="text/css">
    .webgrid-table {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border: solid 1px #000066; /*#98BF21;*/
        background-color: white;
    }

        .webgrid-table td, th {
            border: 1px solid #000099; /*#98BF21;*/
            padding: 3px 7px 2px;
        }

    .webgrid-header {
        background-color: #b3d9ff; /*#A7C942;*/
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .webgrid-footer {
    }

    .webgrid-row-style {
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .webgrid-alternating-row {
        background-color: #e6f2ff; /*#EAF2D3;*/
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }

    .webgrid-selected-row {
        background-color: #ffff66; /*#EAF2D3;*/
        padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1><img src="~/Images/Celero.png" /></h1>
    <p class="lead">Constraints Analysis Application Pushed Orders Grid</p>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Search for Part across reports",  "Select_MSPart", "MaterialSupply", new { id = ViewData["Id"].ToString(), type = ViewData["type"]},null)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Views", "ConstraintsAnalysis", new { id = ViewData["id"], type = ViewData["type"] }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-horizontal" style="float: left">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @if (Model.RwsPrPge == Model.TotalRecords)
                    {
                        <select id="rwsPrPge" name="rwsPrPge">
                            <option value="5">50</option>
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                        </select>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <select id="rwsPrPge" name="rwsPrPge">
                            <option value="0">All</option>
                            <option value="5">50</option>
                        </select>
                    }
                    <input type="submit" value="Rows/Page" />
                    @Html.Hidden("id", (object)ViewData["Id"].ToString())
                    @Html.Hidden("type", (object)ViewData["type"].ToString())
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SearchFilter, new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectFilter, "Value", "Text"),
                        "Select Part for Search", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Search Filter" })*@
                    @Html.DropDownList("m", new SelectList(ViewBag.SelectFilter, "Value", "Text"), "Select Part")
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4" float="right">
                    &emsp;
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="m">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <br /><br />
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="Export" name="Export">
                        <option value="00">No Export</option>
                        <option value="XX">Export to CSV</option>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DlList)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DlList)
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Export" href="/ConstraintsAnalysis/Views">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        if (Model != null)
        {
            <span>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="vam" style="float: left">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Report Selection Menu", "Index", "ConstraintsAnalysis")
                </span>
                &nbsp;
                <span class="vam">
                    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                            caption: "Celero Constraints Grid",
                            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style");
                </span>
            </span>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I forgot the columns: cols on the @grid.GetHtml.
Thank you